# How to write to a text file using Python such a way that I can read it simultaneously in the terminal/gnuplot

Tags: python, file-handling

I am running a long Python program which prints values to a .txt file in an iterative way. I am trying to read the values using terminal "gedit/tail/less" commands and trying to plot them in Gnuplot. But I am not able to read the .txt file till the whole execution is over. What is the correct argument for such file handling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are written when they are closed or when the size of the buffer is too large to store.

That is even when you use file.write("something"), something isn't written in the file till you close the file, or with block is over.

```py
with open("temp.txt","w") as w:
  w.write("hey")
  x=input("touch")
  w.write("\nhello")
  w.write(x)
```

run this code and try to read the file before touch, it'll be empty, but after the with block is over you can see the contents.

If you are going to access the file from many sources, then you have to be careful of this, and also not to modify it from multiple sources.

EDIT: I forgot to say, you have to continuously close the file and open it in append mode if you want some other program to read it while you are writing to the file.